# Why can't I copy a file inside a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have some folders with some codes like `/home/MYFOLDER`. It contains 3 subfolders:

- output folder : contains `myfile.txt`
- script folder : 2 shell script `one.sh` and `two.sh`
- source folder : contains `a.c` and `b.c`

I wrote scripts for `one.sh` and `two.sh` . I am calling `two.sh` from `one.sh`

one.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
#passing 2 argument to two.sh script
two.sh name 12
```

and two.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
textname=$1
value=$2
#getting directory path
PATH="$(pwd)"
#make a copy of file.txt from output folder and create newtextname-$value.txt
/bin/cp "$PATH/output/$textname.txt" "newtextname-$value.txt"
```

Why didn't I get errors when the file does not exist in that path and got the path like this :  `/home/MYFOLDER\r/output/myfile\r.txt`?? Why this `\r` is appended? How to get correct path to access the file? How to get the directory path in shell script? I am using Cygwin to run these scripts.

Comment: the variable you passed in two.sh is name but file name is myfile.txt , you have to pass myfile instead of name

Comment: Did you by chance edit the shell scripts in Notepad on Windows? End of lines should be `\n` only.

Comment: It sounds like you have a windows line ending problem. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for how to correct it. And also, do not use `PATH` as a variable name, as that variable is used for the system paths.

Comment: Your script file is almost certainly using Windows line endings (`\r\n`) rather than Linux/Unix (`\n`). Run `sed -i '' {one,two}.sh` to remove the extra characters.